# Как получить (HTML) тело aspx страницы при ответе сервера "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" на C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Нужно получить исходный код с ошибкой (именно при ответе сервера 500 Internal Server Error) aspx страницы, но чет не как не получается, если в ручную через браузер все нормально,код:

```
source = request.Get("domen.com/rss.aspx").ToString();

using (StreamWriter writer1 = new StreamWriter(@"Log.txt" , true))
{
writer1.WriteLine(source);
writer1.Close();
}
```

**source** пустой всегда с **Respose** тоже такая же беда, все нужные **хидеры** выставлены, не могу понять в чем может быть проблема, и в логах **снифера** все нормально показывает, но прочитать не как не выходит...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, надо было через WebException, рабочий код:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("domen.com/rss.aspx");
                                        {
                                        request.KeepAlive = false;
                                        request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
                                        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                                        request.Proxy = null;

                                        try
                                            {
                                            request.GetResponse();
                                            }
                                        catch (WebException ex)
                                            {
                                            using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                                                {
                                                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                                                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                                reader.Close();

                                                using (StreamWriter writer1 = new StreamWriter(@"Log.txt" , true))
                                                    {
                                                    writer1.WriteLine(text);
                                                    writer1.Close();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
```